# Scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need to do this in jquery with a little animation (the folowing sentece works):

```
window.parent.scroll(coord[0], coord[1]);
```

Does the folowing code to do what I want? because it doesn't, =D

```
$(window.parent).animate({
    scroll: coord
}, 2000);
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question!

Answer (score 3):

You need to animate the `scrollTop` property:

```
$(window.parent).animate({
    scrollTop: 'XXpx',
});
```

Where XX is the amount of pixels from top of the page. `scrollLeft` works for x-dimension.

Or just use the jQuery.scrollTo plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/